# Format a date into mm.dd.yyyy format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a VBA script in which I am trying to convert the string in "yyyymmdd" format to "mm/dd/yyyy" format. However, when I incorporate format function to achieve this, it's showing

```
"Run time error-6": Overflow
```

Can any one help me with this ? The following is  the correspondig VBA code.

```
// NewDate is in the format "yyyymmdd" being extracted out of a file path like "C:\Files\20140611\file.csv"

Required_format=Format(NewDate,"mm/dd/yyyy") // This line shows the error
```

Comment: If it is in string/text format, that won't do. Format function accepts date data type. You will have to manipulate your string date first then use the Format function.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to format this yourself, because `Format` doesn't know that it is dealing with a date, it simply sees a string.

Use something like (psuedo code):

```
y = left(NewDate, 4)
m = mid(NewDate, 5, 2)
d = right(NewDate, 2)

Required_format = m + "/" + d + "/" + y
```

Just be absolutely sure the format is consitant. Any change (especially the padding is notorious) messes up your format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution:

```
CDate(format(NewDate,"mm dd yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method.  As you wrote above, NewDate contains an 8 digit string representing a date in yyyymmdd format.  The following "one liner" will output a date (as a string) in your desired format:

```
Format(Format(NewDate, "@@@@/@@/@@"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```